# How do I set a child element to no animation when the parent element has an animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code. I am trying to make the child h3 elements have no animation and in the meanwhile, the parent .loader element should contain the animation. I tried many ways to stop animating the child h3 elements. but whenever I try, the child element inherits the rotating animation from the parent element and rotates along.

I want the child elements not to have any animation while the parent `.loader` element should still contain the loading animation.

```css
#loader-wrap {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #050505;
  z-index: 800;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-right: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-left: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);   
  animation: rotating 1s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotating 1s linear infinite;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head><title>Loading Animation</title>
  <body>
    <div id="loader-wrap">
      <div class="loader">
        <h3 class="logo-left">TE</h3>
        <h3 class="logo-right">FI</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried .loader > .logo-left, .loader > .logo-right {animation: none}  ?

Comment: yes i tried but it still rotates along.
`.loader .logo-left, .loader .logo-right {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 color: white; 
        animation: none;
}`

This is what i have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can add animation on `.loader:before`

```css
#loader-wrap {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #050505;
  z-index: 800;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.loader:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-right: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-left: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);   
  animation: rotating 1s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotating 1s linear infinite;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}


@keyframes rotating {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<head><title>Loading Animation</title>
<body>
  <div id="loader-wrap">
    <div class="loader">
      <h3 class="logo-left">TE</h3>
      <h3 class="logo-right">FI</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this did not work exactly as i wanted. but this solved my problem and gave me the solution almost. thanks and regards